# Why does starting a new thread before .mainloop() cause .mainloop() to not run?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter, graph

I am trying to test having one class generating data and have that data dynamically updating list variables from another class which then plots the lists by updating them after a certain interval. I've tested just plotting and that doesn't seem to be working either but first I want to figure out why starting a new thread prevents tkinter's event loop from running. Any help is appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import animation
import threading



root = tk.Tk()




class dynamicChart():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.buildChart()
        
    def buildChart(self):
        
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.scatter = ax.scatter(self.x,self.y)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, root)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(pady=10)
        
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()


    def animate(self,i):

        self.scatter.set_offsets([self.x, self.y])
    
    def Ani(self):
        
        self.animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animate, frames = 100, interval = 2000)
        
        
        
class genData():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.chart = dynamicChart()
        
    def generate(self):
        X = 1
        Y = 0
        i = 0
        while True:
            
            time.sleep(1)
            
            X = X*i
            Y = Y + i
    
            self.chart.x.append(X)
            self.chart.y.append(Y)
            
            i+=1
    
StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes = genData()

genData = threading.Thread(target = StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.generate())
genData.start()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Graph It", command = StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.chart.Ani)
button.pack()
  
    

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you really done some research about your problem? Please show some effort! You will find multiple questions same as yours. If you had done enough research and not found anything, then provide those research result in question.

Comment: You need to remove `()` from `StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.generate()`<- this is a call to that method. Whereas the target parameter in Thread requires a callable object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does starting a new thread before .mainloop() cause .mainloop() to not run?

The short answer is "because you aren't starting a new thread".

Consider this code:

```
genData = threading.Thread(target = StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.generate())
```

It is functionally equivalent to this code:

```
result = StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.generate()
genData = threading.Thread(target = result)
```

See the problem? `target` needs to be given a reference to a callable.

```
genData = threading.Thread(target = StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.generate)
```

Comment: That solved the problem, I need to look more into what it means to be a "callable." In your second code snippet I'm not sure what "result" is, is it an object? I thought objects could only be instantiated through a classes __init__ method and only a class method is called(.generate()). Does "result' contain a reference to the action of the "StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes" object calling one of its class methods(.generate())?

Comment: @EECE: _" In your second code snippet I'm not sure what "result" is, is it an object?"_ - it's whatever `StartDataGen_CreateFigureAxes.generate()` returns. In this case it appears to be `None` since you don't explicitly return anything.

Comment: I see now, sorry about that I misread what you said. Makes sense why it doesn't work since I'm just giving it the return value which is nothing!